# Concurrent migrations of Google Compute Engine instances

Tags: google-compute-engine

Google Compute Engine guide says that Google may migrate a VM in order to do maintenance:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/setting-instance-scheduling-options

> By default, standard instances are set to live migrate, where Google
>   Compute Engine automatically migrates your instance away from an
>   infrastructure maintenance event, and your instance remains running
>   during the migration. Your instance might experience a short period of
>   decreased performance, although generally most instances should not
>   notice any difference.

There is a disruption during migration.
Is it possible that Google decides to migrate all instances within a zone at the same time? Is there a maximum to a number of concurrent migrations?

Answer (score -1):

Q: There is a disruption during migration?

A: Yes there is a small period of time where the instance is not running on the old host neither the new one. Here [1] you can see how the process works.

Q: Is it possible that Google decides to migrate all instances within a zone at the same time?

A: It is very unlikely that this escenario happens, as this would implicate that all your Google Compute Engine instances of your project are on the same physical host.

Q: Is there a maximum to a number of concurrent migrations?

A: I don't know the answer to that question but I have addressed to the proper team so maybe they can answer it.

You can find more about the live migration procedure here [2].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/live-migration#how_does_the_live_migration_process_work

[2] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/live-migration

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)